# .NET Core application publish fail

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

My .NET Core 3.1 application stopped publishing suddenly and display the below error,

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0' was not found.
- The following frameworks were found:
  2.1.15 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  2.2.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Below is the dotnet --info output

```
Version:   3.1.101

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.18363
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.1

.NET Core SDKs installed:
2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you send the `dotnet --info` result?

Comment: Post the message as text, not a image

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not screenshots. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3561275

Comment: That's *NOT* a .NET Core 3.1 application. The message says it's a .NET Core 1.0 application. Is this a legacy application? Or did you modify the `csproj` file by hand?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, it's a 3.1 application and worked until yesterday.

Comment: `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0'` that says it's a .NET Core 1.0 application. Have you modified `C:\merge\src\BnA.Services.Web\BnA.Services.Web.csproj` ? What does it contain? The error is there

Comment: No, I didn't do any changes

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo I have added the dotnet --info output

Comment: and show us your `<TargetFramework>` from your `.csproj`

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. In my case, it was the dotnet bundle PrePublishScript command.

```
<Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
```

removing above from my .csproj worked. Not sure why it happened suddenly without even changing the .csproj file.

Comment: Similar issue, removing dotnet bundle resolves the build of a dotnet 3.1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is targeting .NET Core 1.0, but it's not installed.

You have 2.1, 2.2 and 3.1 installed, but not 1.0, that your application needs.

You need to install .NET Core 1.0.

1.0 has been out of support for years and is missing critical fixes. You should think about upgrading this application to a supported .NET or .NET Core release.